# Dealing with null value and JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to use `IFNULL()` function to prevent the result of the query from being null,
 because null values causes errors when result are converted to JSON array.

```
$sql = mysql_query("select IFNULL(status,'nothing'),
    foodname from disease_food,
    food where disease_food.Disease_ID=$d1 or disease_food.Disease_ID=$d2 and    
    Food_ID=$res1 and disease_food.Food_ID=food.ID");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}

$data = json_encode($output);
print($data);
mysql_close();
```

The errors:(when the result is null)

`Undefined variable: output`

Comment: You must use prepared statements these days, that kind of query is dangerous and archaic: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Try `$sql=mysql_query("select IFNULL(status,'nothing'),foodname from disease_food,food where    disease_food.Disease_ID=$d1 or disease_food.Disease_ID=$d2 and    
Food_ID=$res1 and disease_food.Food_ID=food.ID") OR die(mysql_error());` and tell me what error (if any, you get)

Comment: How about locating and fixing that error first?

Comment: @user2012: What's wrong with that?  Were you not expecting `status` to be راض ("satisfied" in Arabic)?

Comment: @eggyal: I think he's looking for a more readable/addressable attribute name, like `IFNULL(status, 'nothing') AS status`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you hava a typo. there is a ' missing before status.

```
   IFNULL(status,'nothing')
```